# How to change paragraph composer using script?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

Is there a script command that can reassign the adobe paragraph composer to 'World paragraph composer'?

The [InDesign ExtendScript API(12.0)](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign12/#about.html) does not seem to have a command.

I basically want to change the type of composer in multiple documents (basically in multiple books. Each book containing approximately 50 documents).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the composer by writing to a story's (or another text item's) `composer` property. The tricky part is to find out what to set it to, as this is also dependent on your locale and differs if you use international versions of InDesign. That's why you need to resort to language independent identifiers. There are scripts out there that can generate all these identifiers for you, however, if you just need this one for the composer property, here you go:

```js
myStory.composer = "$ID/HL Composer Optyca";  // world paragraph composer

// or alternatively, here are the other three common composer values
// myStory.composer = "$ID/HL Single Optyca";  // world single line composer
// myStory.composer = "$ID/HL Composer";  // Adobe paragraph composer
// myStory.composer = "$ID/HL Single";  // Adobe single line composer
```

Comment: What does `$ID/HL` mean?

Comment: There are multiple stories in each document. But the text is contained in only one story. Is there a way to apply the composer for the entire document?

Comment: Sure, get all the stories of the document (`myDoc.stories`) and then just loop over them and assign the the composer value to each one.
Not idea what `HL` in `$ID/HL` actually stands for.

Comment: I did a `document.ChangeComposer()` which automatically changed the composer to world paragraph composer. Will the locale affect this function?

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about this method. This seems not to allow any parameters and always sets it to "optyca" which corresponds to world format. This would then be locale independent. So, in this specific case, this method should be the fastest for your purposes, I guess.

Comment: Building off of @mdomino's answer, I've put together a script which sets all stories in a given document to use the desired composer. You can find the file here: https://github.com/kcole93/SetStoryComposer

Answer (score 0):

There is an property called `Composer` in multiple classes of the API that allows changing the composer.

The `Paragraph` class, `Story` class, etc... has this property.

The `Document` class does not seem to have this `Composer` property. However, it has a method called `changeComposer()`. On applying this method, the composer changed to `Adobe World-Ready Paragraph Composer`.

Hope this helps

Comment: A few notes: Using the string "Adobe World-Ready Paragraph Composer" does work language independent. This might of course not be a problem, if you only ever use a US english version. Going via `app.changeGrepPreferences.composer` is probably much slower then setting the value of a paragraph directly. And lastly, if you need to change entire documents, it will be much faster to change these properties in regard to the stories, not each single paragraph, as a story is the largest text entity in an InDesign document, so will need to change fewer of those. See my answer for details.